# Bash compose new array with the ordered input of other arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I am trying to generate a new array, with the combination of other arrays, respecting a specific sequence. In pure Bash.
Example:

```
numbers=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8);

colors=(red blue green);

loop_sequence=(numbers numbers colors numbers colors colors)
```

Example of out:

```
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
0
1
red
2
blue
green...
```

But I find very difficult to make the internal loops of iterations.
Any help is very welcome.

Comment: duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244759/4667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
numbers=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
colors=(red blue green)
loop_sequence=(numbers numbers colors numbers colors colors)    
numLen=${#numbers[@]}
colLen=${#colors[@]}

arr=() # output array
max=3 # max counter
for ((r=0; r<max; r++)); do
   for i in "${loop_sequence[@]}"; do
      [[ $i == numbers ]] && arr+=("${numbers[$((n++ % numLen))]}") ||
             arr+=("${colors[$((c++)) % colLen]}")
   done
done

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
red
2
blue
green
3
4
red
5
blue
green
6
7
red
8
blue
green
```

Comment: on debian, bash 4 , i get: declare: -n: invalid option

Comment: `declare -n` is new to `bash` 4.3

Comment: @Fredfs: Check updated answer. It should work in older BASH versions as well.

Comment: why your 'max counter' is set to 3 ?

Comment: That is just an example value. Set it to any number you want.

Comment: Please, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941204/bash-how-to-pass-strings-from-array-as-arguments-to-a-command