# BASH: How to pass strings from array as arguments to a command?

Tags: arrays, bash

Each string in "list_of_arrays", is  the name of an array I need to pass to the 'declare' command line.

Something like:

```
for arrayname in "${list_of_arrays[@]}"; do 
declare -A idx=(["$arrayname[0]"]=0 ["$arrayname[1]"]=0 ["$arrayname[2]"]=0 ...)
done
```

How do I make this work for any number of strings? Each string/array name will always be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [indirect variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to accomplish this:

```
foo=(a b c)
baz=(g h i)
bar=(d e f)
list_of_arrays=(foo bar baz)
for aname in "${list_of_arrays[@]}"; do 
    unset idx; declare -A idx
    tmp="${aname}[@]"
    for value in "${!tmp}"; do 
        idx[$value]=0
    done
    # print it out to verify
    declare -p idx
done
```

```
declare -A idx='([a]="0" [b]="0" [c]="0" )'
declare -A idx='([d]="0" [e]="0" [f]="0" )'
declare -A idx='([g]="0" [h]="0" [i]="0" )'
```

---

Well, all of the above is wrong, as the OP wants the array *names* to be the keys of the `idx` array.  As mentioned in the comments:

```
tmp=( "${list_of_arrays[@]/#/[}" ) 
tmp=( "${tmp[@]/%/]=0}" )
eval declare -A idx=( "${tmp[@]}" )
```

Although I would go with the much less clever:

```
declare -A idx
for aname in "${list_of_arrays[@]}"; do idx["$aname"]=0; done
declare -p idx
```

Comment: Hi Glenn! can I use:  tmp=( "${list_of_arrays[@]/#/[}" ) tmp=( "${tmp[@]/%/]=0}" ); declare -A "$(printf '%s  ' "${tmp[@]}")" ?

Comment: That mostly works, except I get this error when I `declare -A idx=( "${tmp[@]}" )`
==> `bash: idx: "${tmp[@]}": must use subscript when assigning associative array`, so you need `eval declare -A idx=( "${tmp[@]}" )`

Comment: However, that leads to `declare -A idx='([bar]="0" [baz]="0" [foo]="0" )'` == do you want the keys if the idx array to be the array **names**, or the array **values**?